# Call View from another View after modifying request (Rest-Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Book_ViewSet:

I have a ViewSet that takes care of all the CRUD operations on a product. Consider Book API, where I can create a book based on **title** and **author**.

ISBN_View:

I have another View that accepts ISBN numbers, looks up the book, gets the **title** and **author** and creates the Book from Model.

What I want:
After parsing ISBN data and getting the book info, I want to create a fresh POST request to the Book_ViewSet with the book data as the body.

I tried looking up best way to do this, but people suggested that modifying current request and sending it to different view is a bad practice.

=============================================================

```py
class Book_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        . . .
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        . . .
        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       . . .
       return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ISBN_view(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    def get(self, request, isbn=None, *args, **kwargs):

        isbn, validation_error = self.validated_isbn(isbn)
        if not isbn:
            return Response(validation_error)

       # Here I use ISBN to search up books, and grab data

       # Here I want to call Book_ViewSet to create the Book instance
       # with the data I grabbed from ISBN


        return Response("bleep bloop")


    def validated_advance_id(self, isbn):
        pass
        # isbn validation goes here.
```

=============================================================

Is this a bad design? any tips on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to call the view, specifically? All the logic involved in creating the instance from the data should be encapsulated in the serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to call the view, because there are different endpoints for each view. isbn url:  /isb/28392839 (its get request) | book url: /book/ (data goes in post body)

Comment: I don't see how those are related. You would define a serializer for Book, and call it from both views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
Is it possible to map the **get** method from ISBN_view to do create?
From what I understand, when **create** method is called it automatically goes to serializer and calls its **create** method. How can I change this behaviour?